# Control.ST pure type

Tags: idris, state-monad

`pure : (result : ty) -> STrans m ty (out_fn result) out_fn` from http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/st/state.html#strans-primitive-operations

I'm not sure what `(out_fn result) out_fn` means. Is it about constraining `out_fn` to be a function of `result`? Does it actually say anything about the input resource list?

The given explanation seems to be *"...provided that the current list of resources is correct when producing that value"* but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
STrans : (m : Type -> Type) ->
         (result : Type) ->
         (inRes : Resources) ->
         (outRes : result -> Resources) ->
         Type
```

You see that the input resources don't depend on the result of a computation, but the output resources do. Now, let's say we have

```
MyResultType : Type
myResult : MyResultType
```

What's the type of `pure myResult`? It is `STrans m MyResultType (f myResult) f`. What are the input resources? `f myResult`, which could be anything. What are the output resources? Well, that depends on the result. But, this is `pure`, so the result is always `myResult`, and so the output resources are also `f myResult`. You see that the signature of `pure` is saying that the input and output resources can be anything, and that "anything" depends on `f` and `myResult`, but they have to be the same "anything"s no matter what.

I believe an equivalent way to see the type of `pure` is

```
pure' : (result : ty) -> STrans m ty resources (const resources)
```

Which is probably clearer. I don't know why this signature is not used.